# Is the return statement atomic?

Tags: java, concurrency

I pasted some code about Java concurrency:

```
public class ValueLatch <T> {

    @GuardedBy("this") private T value = null;
    private final CountDownLatch done = new CountDownLatch(1);

    public boolean isSet() {
        return (done.getCount() == 0);
    }

    public synchronized void setValue(T newValue) {
        if (!isSet()) {
            value = newValue;
            done.countDown();
        }
    }

    public T getValue() throws InterruptedException {
        done.await();
        synchronized (this) {
            return value;
        }
   }

}
```

Why does `return value;` need to be synchronized???

Is the return statement not atomic??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The return does not need to be synchronized.  Since `CountDownLatch.countDown()` is not called until after the value is set for the last time, `CountDownLatch.await()` ensures that value is stable before it is read and returned.

The developer who wrote this was probably not quite sure of what he was doing (concurrency is difficult and dangerous) or, more likely, his use of the `GuardedBy` annotation on `value` caused his build system to emit a warning on the `return`, and some other developer synchronized it unnecessarily just to make the warning go away.

I say 'some other developer', because this class otherwise seems to be specifically designed to allow `getValue()` to proceed without locking once the value has been set.

Comment: the example code above is from <<Java concurrency in practice>> ，the book is pretty old, so i want to ask does return statement is atomic in Java 1.5 or 1.6?

Comment: Yes, the return statement is atomic in every way that that question makes sense, but the right question is whether or not it is guaranteed to see the right value... and it is.  It's been this way since Java 1.5 when the java memory model was fixed.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Why? When Thread A (calling `setValue`) wrote to `value` but did not exit the synchronized function yet, Thread B (not in a synchronized block) may see the old value of `value`. Only when Thread A exits the synchronized function and Thread B enters a synchronized block on the same lock the Java Memory Model guarantees that the new value is visible to Thread B, or am I missing something?

Comment: Ah, I see that what I was missing is the "Memory consistency effects" remark at the end of the `CountDownLatch` JavaDoc. Never mind :-)

Answer (score 3):

The return statement needs to perform a read operation over *value*.

The read operation is atomic for *most* primitives, but you're dealing with a generic, meaning you won't know *value*'s type.

For that reason, the return should be synchronized.

Comment: Java generics use type erasure, so you *do* know `value`'s type -- it's `Object`.  Furthermore, reading any object-typed field is guaranteed to be atomic and will always produce an object-typed value, although memory barriers are required when transferring a value from one thread to another to ensure that the value read is up to date.

Comment: Reading of references is always atomic. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7

Comment: I was misinformed, thank you for correcting me.
So it is useless to force synchronization here

Answer (score 2):

`return value` does *not* need to be synchronized:

- reads of references is atomic according to the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7): "Writes to and reads of references are always atomic, ..."
- each thread reading `value` is guaranteed to so see its latest value as according to the [Java Memory Model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) `value = newValue` *happens-before* `done.countDown()`, which *happens-before* `done.await()`, which *happens-before* `return value`. By transitivity `value = newValue` thus *happens-before* `return value`.